# Good Strategy for Message Queuing?

Tags: sql-server, azure, message-queue

I'm currently designing an application which I will ultimately want to move to Windows Azure. In the short term, however, it will be running on a server which I will host myself.

The application involves a number of separate web applications - some of these are essentially WCF services which receive data, and some are sites for users to manage data. In addition, there will need to be a worker service running in the background which will process data in various ways.

I'm very keen to use a decoupled architecture for this. Ideally I'm wanting the components (i.e. web apps and worker service) to know as little as possible about each other. It seems like using a message queue will be the best solution here - the web apps can enqueue messages with work units into the queue and the worker service can pick them out and process them as needed.

However, I want to work out a good set of technologies for doing this, bearing in mind that I'll ultimately be moving to Azure and want to minimise the amount of re-work I'll need to do when I migrate to the cloud. Azure has a Queue component built in which looks ideal for my needs. What I'd like to do is create something myself which will mimic this as closely as possible.

It looks like there are several options (I'm using .NET on Windows, with a SQL Server 2005 back end) - the ones I've found so far are:

- MSMQ
- SQL Server service broker
- Rolling my own using a database table and some stored procs

I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions for this - or if anyone has done anything similar and has advice on things to do/to avoid. I realise that every situation is different, but in this case I think my queuing requirements are pretty generic so I'd love to hear anyone else's thoughts about the best way to do this.

Thanks in advance,

John

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you have Azure in mind, perhaps you should start straight on Azure as the APIs and semnatics are significantly different between Azure queues and any of MSMQ or SSB.

A quick 3048 meters comparison of MSMQ vs. SSB (I'll leave a custom table-as-queue out of comparison as it really depends how you implement it...)

- **Deployment**: MSMQ is a Windows component, SSB is a SQL compoenent. SSB requires a SQL instance to store any message, so disconencted clients need access to an instance (can be Express). MSMQ requires deployment of MSMQ on the client (part of OS, but optional install).
- **Programmability**: MSMQ offers a fully fledged, supported, WCF channel. SSB offers only an experimental WCF channel at http://ssbwcf.codeplex.com
- **Performance**: SSB will be significantly faster than MSMQ in transacted mode. MSMQ will be faster if let operate in untransacted mode (best effort, unordered, delivery)
- **Queriability**: SSB queues can be SELECTE-ed uppon (view any message, full SQL JOIN/WHERE/ORDER/GROUP power), MSMQ queues can be peeked (only next message)
- **Recoverability**: SSB queues are integrated in the database so they are backed up and restored with the database, keeping a consitent state with the application state. MSMQ queues are backed up in the NT file backup subsytem, so to keep the backup in sync (coherent) the queue *and* database have to be suspended.
- **Transactions** (since every enqueue/dequeue is *always* accompanied by a database update): SSB is fully integrated in SQL so dequeueing and enqueueing are local transaction operations. MSMQ is a separate TM (Transaction Manager) so queue/dequeue has to be a Distributed Transaction operation to enroll both SQL and MSMQ in the transaction.
- **Management and Monitoring**: both equaly bad. No tools whatsoever.
- **Correlated Messages** processing: SSB can block processing of correlated message by concurent threads via built-in [Conversation Group Locking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171615.aspx).
- **Event Driven**: SSB has [Activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171617.aspx) to launch stored procedures, MSMQ uses [Windows Activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752246.aspx?wt.slv=ColumnA) service. Similar. SSB though has self load balancing capalities due to the way WAITFOR(RECEIVE) and MAX_QUEUE_READERS interact.
- **Availability**: SSB piggybacks on the SQL Server High Availability story, it can work either in a clustered or in database miroring environment. MSMQ rides the Windows clustering story only. Database Mirroring is much cheaper than clustering as a HA solution.

In addition I'd add that SSB and MSMQ differ significantly at the level ofthe primitive they offer: SSB primitive is a *conversation*, while MSMQ primitive is a *message*. Think TCP vs. UDP semantics.

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful. It looks like MSMQ might be a better option for our purposes - I guess one big next step will be to compare MSMQ to Azure Queuing. I know, for example, that Azure doesn't guarantee messages will be delivered in order (or only once) so I'll need to check this against MSMQ to see what the corresponding behaviour is. But thanks again for this - it's a very informative comparison.

Answer (score 10):

Pick a queue back end that works for you, or that is better suited to your environment. @Remus has given a great comparison between MSMQ and SSB.  MSMQ is going to be the easier one to implement, but has some notable limitations, while SSB is going to feel very heavy as its at the other end of the spectrum.

**Have It Your Way**
To minimize the rework from you applications, abstract the queues access behind an interface, and then provide an implementation for the queue transport you ultimately decide to go with.  When its time to move to Azure, or another queue transport, you just provide a new implementation of your interface.

You get to control the semantics of how you want to interact with the queue to give a consistent usable API from your applications.

A rough idea might be:

```
interface IQueuedTransport
{
  void SendMessage(XmlDocument);
  XmlDocument ReceiveMessage();
}

public class MSMQTransport : IQueuedTransport {}
public class AzureQueueTransport : IQueuedTransport {}
```

You may not be building the be-all queuing transport, just what meets your needs.  If you work with Xml, pass xml.  If you work in byte arrays, pass byte arrays. :)

Good luck!
Z

Answer (score 0):

Use Win32 [Mailslots](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365576%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  They will be reliable on a single server, are easy to implement, and do not require any extra software.